# RESTlet 2.0 tutorial application does not work on appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, gwt, restlet, restlet-2.0

I have been playing with the source code available from the [following tutorial](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html).

The GWT/GAE application works in development mode, however when its deployed, the server always returns the response in the JSON format.

I am using the Restlet 2.0 Testing jars, and have also included the dependent libraries.

thank you

Comment: I switched the Testing jars to the Unstable jars, and its now working.

Comment: BTW, what is the desired representation format, if not JSON?

Comment: gwt-rpc :D 

I'm mainly using restlet for communication with an android client...maybe also a public api.

Comment: I used to use Restlet ON GAE. It was giving me a lot of trouble. Since then I'm using Jersey and it works out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem you are now experiencing:

[Restlet POSTing JSON to Appengine error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051397/restlet-posting-json-to-appengine-error/)

As described in my own answer I managed to get it working after much fiddling.

Since then I switched to [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider:

#### Editions

You need to use the GAE edition of Restlet for the server-side app, and the GWT for the client-side app. Neither will suffice for both. For this reason, the two apps are separate projects in [the tutorial archive](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/304-restlet.html1.). So make sure you're using the appropriate edition for each side.

#### Object/Representation Conversion/Serialization and Extensions

I believe that with Restlet 2.0, when a class method annotated with an HTTP method returns a Java object, and doesn't specify how it should be serialized -- converted to a representation -- then Restlet will defer to whichever Restlet extensions are in the classpath which implement this.

In the tutorial, the server-side app includes this jar: "org.restlet.ext.jackson: Jackson extension used to generate JSON representations of the contact resource" -- which I believe is the reason that the response is JSON; the framework is deferring to the extension, which is converting the object into a JSON representation.

Therefore, if, for example, you wanted the framework to automatically serialize your objects into XML, you could remove the Jackson extension JAR from the classpath, and instead include [the XStream extension](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/28-restlet/264-restlet.html). I believe that would cause the framework to serialize the objects as XML.

The wiki page for [ConverterService](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/27-restlet/331-restlet/360-restlet.html) lists the various conversions which the framework supports, and which modules enable them.

HTH!

Comment: I have been using the right editions.

I was thinking that the client sets in the HTTP header what formats it accepts as a return type, and the framework on the server side would transparently return the correct type. Is this right? It seems like that form the above mentioned tutorial.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I do think that which extensions are in the classpath does determine which formats the converter service can provide.